# Should I use JSON or related tables to represent a relation in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, relations

I know it is possible to store JSON in Cassandra, and I also know that Cassandra is a structured query language. Because of these two informations, I am unable to determine whether I should store some data as JSON or whether I should add tables.

I need to achieve the following: a customer can have multiple addresses, and an address is unique to this customer.

Since I have been used to do this in MySQL, I would intuitively represent this relation with tables:

```
customers <- 1 to N - addresses
```

However I do observe that some data can be stored as JSON, and I cannot find a clear answer on the Internet. Since it is not required to make the addresses generic (because they are unique), I could use JSON.

Should I represent this relation with JSON stored in a column or with a related table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First up, we generally do not recommend storing data as JSON because it is not flexible and not optimised for CQL queries which matters a lot when it comes to performance and scalability.

It is almost always better to parse the elements of the JSON and map each of the fields into CQL columns.

Second, normalising the data into customers and addresses tables is the old way of modelling data for RDBMS. In Cassandra, the first principle of data modelling is to design a table for each and every application query.

In your case, it is quite easy to model customers with multiple addresses. If you have application queries like:

- "Get shipping address for customer X"
- "Get billing address for customer Y"

then you could design the CQL table so that it is partitioned by customer, with each customer having one or more rows of addresses:

```
    customerid text,
    address_type text,
    street text,
    city text,
    zip int
    PRIMARY KEY (customerid, address_type)
)
```

To get the shipping address for a customer:

```
SELECT street, city, zip FROM addresses_by_customer
    WHERE customerid = ?
    AND address_type = 'shipping'
```

Similarly to get the billing address for a customer:

```
SELECT street, city, zip FROM addresses_by_customer
    WHERE customerid = ?
    AND address_type = 'billing'
```